# Why is $\lim\limits_{x\to a} e^x = e^{\lim\limits_ {x\to a} x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> This is a confusion that I have had for a long time. " Why is $\lim\limits_{x\to a}  e^x = e^{\lim\limits_ {x\to a} x}$?"

Is there any proof or logic behind? Please explain. I have googled this and I have not received any satisfying answers

Comment: It's what we call *continuity*.

Comment: If you want to know why $e^x$ is continuous, you'll need to provide a definition of the function $e^x$ that you're comfortable with. For example, is it $\frac{1}{0!} + \frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!}$? Or maybe it's the unique solution to the IVP $y' = y, y(0) = 1$?

Comment: I do not think this question should be closed. In particular, I don't think it is "missing context of other details". Its just a thought someone is having, and its the kind of thought which admits a good answer in the form of a reference to a book or some course notes.

Comment: Here is a relevant post on the definition of $a^x$: [What does $2^x$ really mean when $x$ is not an integer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132703/what-does-2x-really-mean-when-x-is-not-an-integer/133238#133238). For the result mentioned by Siong Thye Goh, see [Proving that $\lim\limits_{ x \rightarrow 0}{f(g(x))}=f(\lim\limits_{ x \rightarrow 0}g(x))$ when $f$ is continuous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882367/proving-that-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-0fgx-f-lim-limits-x-rightar?rq=1)

Comment: @TheoBendit: It's definitely not the quadratic you provided! =P

Comment: Until you **define precisely** what "$e^x$" means, your question cannot really be answered properly. Separate from that, I strongly recommend that you start learning proper real analysis from a proper textbook such as Spivak's Calculus.

Comment: @user21820 It would make continuity easier though.

Comment: @TheoBendit: Lol it sure does!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For continuous function, the function of the limit is the limit of the function.

$$f(\lim_{x \to a}x) = \lim_{x \to a}f(x)$$

Exponentiation is a continuous function.

Comment: Please be more precise. Exponentiation is continuous on a certain domain, not everywhere that it is useful to be defined.